# custom broadcast receiver permission

Tags: android

i have an Activity where inside a method a send a broadcast to a custom receiver located in Activity's Fragment...i would like to set a permission as a second parameter of sendBroadcast so my receiver can receive only specific broadcasts...

Activity's sendBroadcast():

```
@Override
public void update(Observable observable, Object connectionStatus) {
    Log.e(debugTag, connectionStatus+"");
    intent = new Intent("networkStateUpdated");
    intent.putExtra("connectivityStatus", (int) connectionStatus);
    sendBroadcast(intent, "mypermission");
}
```

initialization of custom Receiver inside Fragment's onActivityCreated

```
 broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                connectionStatus = intent.getExtras().getInt("connectivityStatus");

            }
        };

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getActivity().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("networkStateUpdated"), "mypermission", null);

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}
```

setting "mypermission" as second parameter of sendBroadcast is apparently not working..

Comment: I *strongly* recommend that you switch from this to `LocalBroadcastManager`, or some other form of in-process event bus (e.g., Square's Otto, greenrobot's EventBus). Do not use inter-process communication as a means of talking from one piece of your app to another piece of your app. Not only will `LocalBroadcastManager` or an event bus be faster, but you will not have this security concern.

Comment: you are right..i read the documentation about LocalBroadcastManager and indeed suits perfectly my app needs..thanks at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use system broadcasts (e.g., `sendBroadcast()` called on `Context`) when you need to send messages between processes.

Within a process, using system broadcasts adds IPC overhead and security concerns. Instead, use some sort of in-process event bus. Personally, I use [greenrobot's EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). `LocalBroadcastManager` is part of the Android Support libraries. Others prefer [Square's Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) or other event bus implementations. These are less expensive in terms of overhead, and they are private to your app, so there are no new security concerns.